What is the hardest bike mechanics task for an amateur cyclist?
For me it is the lacing and truing the wheel. It's very challenging to get a wheel to perfect trueness. What do you think?

Building your own frame!

This is not considered as bike mechanics. It's engineering and designing.

Full service of a suspension fork. With no parts available in the shops.

One that I don't recommend is servicing a Shimano freehub.  I have done it successfully, but first I had to make a tool because they don't sell them.  Despite being made out of 3mm thick steel (the thickest that would go in the slot), it bent enough that I couldn't use it a 2nd time.
When you do get in there and clean everything up, you find 50 tiny ball bearings, without much to retain them while you put the freehub back together.  Luckily replacement freehubs aren't expensive

I think wheelbuilding definitely is the one that requires the most skill, and as a job that is easiest to do poorly, resulting in a wheel that doesn't stand the test of time. And even when the skill has been learned, if you don't build wheels as your dayjob, you should allocate 5 hours for a single wheel to get a good result.
However, there are other hard things. For example, replacement of a hub press-fit bearing cup might require improvised tools and the manufacturer doesn't officially support that. Also, I would say any press-fit task requires specialized tools and is tricky to get it right. For example, installation of headset crown race or headset bearing cups with improvised tools can be hard.
Furthermore, replacement of a frame might require an amount of time that could actually be more than building a single wheel, and could require shopping new components and lots of specialized tools.

Are you really sure about wheelbuilding? I'd say that for a person with basic mechanical aptitude, no experience and enough patience to check every step instead of rushing it should take a couple of hours. Rushing and redoing can of course increase it a lot.

I'm with @ojs on that.  With decent instructions and patience it's not going to be 5 hours even the first time (my first full build was with one arm in a sling and didn't take that long).  And with wheelbuilding it has to have gone very badly wrong to not be able to correct it, or worst case slacken it off and start again.  Screwing up press fit is worse. And truing on the frame is fine; with a couple of steel rulers and some clips (better, magnets and a steel frame) you can get it true to well within a mm.
